# Use higher order functions to concise scala code

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I'm new to Scala and trying to write some programs to get better at it. I wrote a flow (version 1) that is very Java-like and I'm trying to write it using higher order functions (version 2). 
**version 1:**

```
    val entry: Option[Int] = getEntry()

    if (entry.isDefined) {
      val cachedEntry = entry.get
      if (cachedEntry.state.isActive) {
        return cachedEntry
      } else {
        Cache.invalidateCachedEntry(cachedEntry)
      }
    }

    Cache.createNewEntry()
```

**version 2:**

```
    val entry: Option[Int] = getEntry()

    entry.filter(_.state.isActive).orElse((() => {
      Cache.invalidateCachedEntry _
      Option(Cache.createNewEntry())
    })()).get
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach or there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: can you post the structure of getEntryResponse. Other your explanation is wrong. Because, above you define that `entry` is optional `Int`, but later you cal `.state.isActive`.

Comment: The two don't appear to be quite the same. If `entry` is `None` then V1  does **not** call `Cache.invalidateCachedEntry()` but in V2 it **does**.

Comment: what do you need to return as a result at the very end?

Comment: @Bob 1) that was a typo, it should've been `cachedEntry.state.isActive`. I've updated the question. 2) I need to return an integer value (returned by `createNewEntry()`, not an optional value)

Comment: @jwvh you are right, that is different. Though `invalidateCachedEntry` simply removes the `cachedEntry` from the map so it should be fine either way (should be just a no-op).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider following scenerio:

```
case class Entry(state: AnyState)
case class AnyState(isActive: Boolean = true)

object Cache {
  def invalidateCachedEntry(entry: Entry): Unit = println("cleaned")
}

def getEntry: Option[Entry] = Some(Entry(AnyState()))

val optEntry: Option[Entry] = getEntry

val result: Option[Entry] = optEntry match {
  case Some(entry) if entry.state.isActive =>
    entry // do something
     println("did something")
     Some(entry)
  case Some(entry) =>
    Cache.invalidateCachedEntry(entry)
    None
  case _ =>
   println("Entry not found")
   None
}
```

This would be a one scenario. In general you should return something. But sometimes you don't have enough information. Such cases you can return `Option` and if you want to throw an error you can use Either

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `match` for clarity：

```
getEntry() match {
  case Some(entry) if entry.state.isActive => entry
  case opt => opt.foreach(Cache.invalidateCachedEntry); Cache.createNewEntry()
}
```